# Script to auto set gmail From address based on filter

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I have multiple from sender addresses linked to my gmail.

I want to execute a script that would set the FROM address from the list according to the filter on that email.

Comment: What have you tried? Include the code you have already written and what you have found.

Comment: I dont have a script at the moment, I am looking for one.

Comment: What kind of script are you looking for? Did you do any search/research about this?